# how do we categorize verbs that come after copula verbs?

Tags: syntax, copula

(1) The bird seems to eat.

Would *eat* be a verb?

I thought that it would be but now I'm having second thoughts about whether it's an adjective or a verb.

Comment: What definition are you using of "verb"?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive

Comment: Yes it is a verb; it's the verb of a short subordinate clause called an "infinitive clause", which uses the base form of its verb, and usually comes after _to_ : _to go, to see, to like, to live, to die, to be, to be happy, to be a doctor_.

Comment: As Jl says, it's a verb. More specifically, it's a verb heading a catenative clause functioning as complement of the catenative verb "seem".